# Unexpected data found. Trailing data

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to persist data from the client to my database and I have a trouble with the timestamp.

```php
public function post(UpdateRequest $request){
    $update = new UpdateEvent();
    $update->src = $request->get('src');
    $update->title = $request->get('title');
    $update->sapo = $request->get('description');
    $update->created_at = $request->get('created_at');
    $update->img = $request->get('image');
    $update->save();
    return view('update.notification');
}
```

I'm getting the following exception:

> InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 582:
>   Unexpected data found.
>   Trailing data

Can you help me?

Comment: What format is the date you are passing in from the request?

Comment: Paste code not images.

Comment: which line is 582?

Comment: seems like `$request->get('created_at')` has wrong value

Answer (score 3):

When a column is considered a date, you may set its value to a UNIX timestamp, date string (Y-m-d), date-time string, and of course a DateTime / Carbon instance, and the date's value will automatically be correctly stored in your database:

[Source](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/unexpected-data-found-unexpected-data-found-trailing-data).

Answer (score 0):

When a column is considered a date, you may set its value to a UNIX timestamp, date string (Y-m-d), date-time string, and of course a DateTime / Carbon instance, and the date's value will automatically be correctly stored in your database:

I'm not sure of the correct fix but I think the current issue is because this field is listed in `$dates`.
Try to remove it from `$dates` array in your model.